# How to import socket.io-client in a angular 2 application?

Tags: javascript, angular, socket.io

I want to include sockets.io-client in my angular 2 application. First I installed socket.io-client, installed typings:

```
npm install socket.io-client --save
typings install socket.io-client --save --ambient
```

Next step was to include socket.io-client into my index.html:

```
 <script src="node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"></script>
```

In my component, I am importing sockets.io:

```
import * as io from 'socket.io-client'
```

And then using it:

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
socket.on('event', function(data:any){
   console.log(data);
}.bind(this));
```

This fails with:

```
zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:3001/socket.io-client 404 (Not Found)
(index):18 Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3001/socket.io-client
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you are using angular cli check my answer in this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38191549/angular2-cli-socket-io-3rd-party-library-import/38786415#38786415

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In order to register the module so you can import it, you need to include it in you SystemJS configuration.

```
System.config({
    packages: {
        ...
        "socket.io-client": {"defaultExtension": "js"}
    },
    map: {
        "socket.io-client": "node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"
    }
});
```

And change your import to:

<s>`import io from 'socket.io-client';`</s>
    `import * as io from "socket.io-client`

Also, you don't need the import in the script tag anymore, so remove:

```
<script src="node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Finally, if you like to add the typings, add in your `typings.json`:

```
{
  "ambientDependencies": {
    ...
    "socket-io-client":"github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/socket.io-client/socket.io-client.d.ts#7de6c3dd94feaeb21f20054b9f30d5dabc5efabd"
  }
}
```

P.S. Int the future, change the hash in the typings to the latest commit hash.

Comment: Thanks. Works like magic now. Just one thing, import io from 'socket.io-client'; fails compilation with: "Module ''socket.io-client'' has no default export." so it has to be import * as io from "socket.io-client" as per https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues/221

Comment: @simonaco Thanks for the correction. I don't actually use socket.io, I just made a bad guess :)

Comment: @RobertBroden I get the latest commit hash from the [DefinitelyTyped Repo](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped). For example, for `socket.io-client`, you should be able to find the hash on the top of the [page](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/socket.io-client). But, for some reason it doesn't show up for me right now. It's stuck on `Fetching latest commit…`. Probably just a temporary issue

Comment: @Abdulrahman Thanks! Page was updated right after you posted this. Message: "Sorry, we had to truncate this directory to 1,000 files. 1,725 entries were omitted from the list." I don't see socket.io-client :( README.md gives instructions though

Answer (score 16):

This is a late answer since I just had this problem and installing correct types  [via npm](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1278) solved it for me:

```
npm install @types/socket.io-client --save
```

This package contains type definitions for `socket.io-client`, so if you are getting type errors this should fix it.

Comment: Doing the first Answer + this answer solved my problem. No need for typings install socket.io-client --save --ambient and editting the tsconfig.json

Answer (score 11):

I also had problems while trying to import socket.io into my project and here is how I resolved it.

- Use Angular 2 (rc.6)
- Based on Systemjs
- [From the skeleton on Angular 2
  samples](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/README.md)
- Node : 5.3.0
- Mac OSX El Capitan

Here we go :

1) Edit your systemjs.config.js file as it :

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    map: {
      ... here my stuff ...
      "socket.io-client": 'npm:socket.io-client'
    },
    packages: {
      ... here my stuff ...
      "socket.io-client": {
        main: './socket.io.js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

2) Open your project in a shell then exec the following line :
usually we tell you to do :

```
npm install socket.io-client --save
typings install socket.io-client --save --ambient
```

But you might received a message that told you that the ambiant flag is deprecated and that you should use global instead. But you'll quickly see that it won't work either. So i propose you something else (well errors logs will give you hints, but you probably won't understand it if you didn't go [there](https://github.com/typings/typings/issues/573) before) :

```
typings install dt~socket.io-client --save --global
```

3) Open your component that require socket.io then add at the top of your file :

```
import * as io from "socket.io-client";
```

then go down and add :

```
export class MessageComponent implements OnInit {
  socket:any = null;

  constructor() {
      this.socket = io('http://localhost:1337');
  }
  ... here my stuff ...
}
```

Where 1337 is the port of your node server containing socket.io that has been launched.

Now, all is ready, you can directly make your request :

```
this.socket.emit('sendMessage', {content:'it works !'});
```

Hope I help :), good luck with your project

Answer (score 1):

```
angular-cli: 0.0.39 
node: 6.2.2 
os: win32 x64
```

I tried to import socket.io-client into an angular2 app generated with the [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) but i can't get it to work.

**chat.component.ts**

```
import * as io from "socket.io-client";

@Component({
  ...
})
export class ChatAppComponent {
  ...
}
```

**system-config.ts**

```
/** Map relative paths to URLs. */
const map: any = {
    "socket.io-client": "vendor/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"
};

/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
    "socket.io-client": {"defaultExtension": "js"}
};
```

**angular-cli-build.js**

```
var Angular2App = require('angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
      'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
      'zone.js/dist/*.js',
      'es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
      'reflect-metadata/*.js',
      'rxjs/**/*.js',
      '@angular/**/*.js',
      'socket.io-client/socket.io.js'
    ]
  });
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
      "dependencies": {
        ...
        "socket.io-client": "^1.4.8",
        "systemjs": "0.19.26"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        ...
        "typescript": "^1.8.10",
        "typings": "
      }
}
```

**typings.json**

```
{
  "ambientDevDependencies": {
    "angular-protractor": "registry:dt/angular-protractor#1.5.0+20160425143459",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160412134438",
    "selenium-webdriver": "registry:dt/selenium-webdriver#2.44.0+20160317120654"
  },
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "es6-shim": "registry:dt/es6-shim#0.31.2+20160317120654",
  },
  "globalDependencies": {
    "socket.io-client": "registry:dt/socket.io-client#1.4.4+20160317120654"
  }
}
```