# Errors when importing socket.io-client in Angular 2 app

Tags: angular, socket.io

I'm trying to use the socket.io client in my angular 2 app and installed it and typings

I'm just importing from 'socket.io-client';

but somehow I get tons of errors from that:

[image]

I can use the lib in my index.html if I load the script from a cdn and just put the init code in a `<script>` tag but I can't use it in my actual angular 2 app.

What am I doing wrong here?

This is my boilerplate: https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed

The examples for socket.io seem outdated which is why I avoided them.

this is all i'm doing and already getting those errors:

```
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
[...]
var socket = io('127.0.0.1');
```

So the issue seems to be related to SystemJS in someway. 
This https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed/wiki/Add-external-dependency suggests I can add the socket.io-client and it should add all dependencies automaticly that doesn't seem the case though.

I've tried the full example but that won't work either.

Comment: It looks to me like you should be using socket.io.js which is specifically design for the browser.

Comment: I am using socket.io-client which was recommended for angular 2 in multiple places

Comment: put some code on how you are trying to import it?

Comment: @Ajey added some more code

Comment: better, put your code on a github repo and give me the link. Thats a lot easier :)

Comment: @Ajey it's up on github.com/gempir/spamchamp

Comment: @gempir shouldn't it be io.connect(url) ?

Comment: @Ajey the official docs say no https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client , I tried anyway didn't work though

Answer (score 2):

Im using socket.io client in my angular 2 application, and have no problems with it. First of all you should not put `script` tag to socket.io-client in your `index.hml`. Second you need these lines in your system.js configuration:

```
{
  packages: {
      "socket.io-client": {"defaultExtension": "js"}
  },

  map: {
    "socket.io-client": "node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"
  }
}
```

Then you simply use it:

```
import * as io from "socket.io-client";
io.connect(url, { /* ... */ });
```

Comment: I've tried something similar before but I'm just unsure how to make it work. Here is my config file from the seed project (https://github.com/gempir/spamchamp/blob/master/tools/config/seed.config.ts), I tried adding in the several suggested places but that didn't work.

Comment: just add these lines to package and map sections and you'll get it working

Comment: I did but i'm still having the same issue :/

Comment: It looks like you added it to: SYSTEM_CONFIG_DEV in seed.config.ts (from the github repo I see in the comments above) and it looks like maybe you might need to add it here too: SYSTEM_BUILDER_CONFIG.

Answer (score 0):

based  on [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1278) which was mentioned in [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37090031/how-to-import-socket-io-client-in-a-angular-2-application)
you should use `npm install @types/socket.io-client --save`

Comment: This was answered 4 months ago with a better answer.

Comment: @George giving that github link I provided did gave this answer relating to an issue with the accepted answer, I don't think the accepted answer is better.