# How to setup socket.io-client with angular2

Tags: angular, socket.io

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37090031/how-to-import-socket-io-client-in-a-angular-2-application), I think there is a change in node_module now main file is `./lib/index.js`, but after doing this also, I'm getting issue socket.io-parser not found, debug not found etc.I think issue is related to socket.io library created by **browser-sync** this is my [error console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGGyr.png)