# Importing Socket.io client in Angular 2, getting dependencies error

Tags: javascript, angular, socket.io

I trying add a Socket.io client to my Angular 2 app using the approach [How to import socket.io-client in a angular 2 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37090031/how-to-import-socket.io-client-in-a-angular-2-application)

But now I am getting below errors of the dependencies of the Socket.io client's JavaScript file.

[image]

Below is the TypeScript file

```
import { Component, OnInit,NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { GroundService } from '../../services/ground.service';
import { Ground } from '../../../Ground';

import * as io from "socket.io-client";


@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'ground',
    templateUrl: 'ground.component.1.html',
    styleUrls: ['ground.component.css']
})

export class GroundComponent{

    ground: Ground[];
    countttt : Number =0;
    constructor(private groundService:GroundService,private ngZone:NgZone){
        const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:30003');
        this.groundService.getGround()
        .subscribe(ground => {
            console.log(ground);
            this.ground = ground;        
        });
      socket.on("on:chat message", (data) => {
          console.log("aa");
    });
    }
}
```

My typing.json

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160725163759",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160909174046",
    "socket.io-client": "registry:dt/socket.io-client#1.4.4+20160317120654"
  }
}
```

Below are the dependencies in the first couple of lines of the Socket.io-client.js file that I am importing in the above TypeScript file. So basically when it imports the Socket.io client in the TS file, it is not able to find the files in gives error.

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var parser = require('socket.io-parser');
var Emitter = require('component-emitter');
var toArray = require('to-array');
var on = require('./on');
var bind = require('component-bind');
var debug = require('debug')('socket.io-client:socket');
var hasBin = require('has-binary');
```

Below is node module folder in the Socket.io client folder that I am importing

[node module folder in the Socket.io client folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z91UR.png)

Below is the system.config.js

```
  System.config({
        map: {
             "socket.io-client": "node_modules/socket.io-client/lib/socket.js",
        },
        packages: {

             "socket.io-client": {"defaultExtension": "js"},
        }
)};
```

Comment: I'd suggest to give us more examples of the code in your app that tries to import these libraries

Comment: @Isigiel i have added some more details. Please have a look now. Thanks !

Comment: @KshitijMehta , have you solved the problem ?

Comment: Yeah. I was passing in the incorrect URL. in the System.config for socket.io-client. @Pra

Answer (score 0):

I was passing in the incorrect URL. in the System.config for socket.io-client. – Kshitij Mehta