# Using socket.io to send data from Sails.js server to Angular2 client side

Tags: angular, socket.io, sails.js

I'm trying to emit a message from my server side Sails application to the front end Angular2. i want both client and server side to be in the same app, so after some searching I found this [repo](https://github.com/xmaestro/sails-angular2). I had to import socket.io in typescript with the help of another stack overflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37090031/how-to-import-socket-io-client-in-a-angular-2-application) and added `@types/socket.io-client` and `socket.io-client` in my package json. I will include all of my files.
This is my initial vies/layout.ejs file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%=typeof title == 'undefined' ? 'New Sails App' : title%></title>

    <!-- Viewport mobile tag for sensible mobile support -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <!--STYLES-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/importer.css">
    <!--STYLES END-->

    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%- body %>

    <!--SCRIPTS-->
    <script src="/js/dependencies/sails.io.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <!--SCRIPTS END-->

    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

in my system.js.config.js file I've added `"socket.io-client":           'node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js'` to my map and `'socket.io-client': {defaultExtension: 'js'}` to packages.
In my component I include it with `import * as io from "socket.io-client";` and after that I've

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(){}

    ngOnInit() {
        let socket = io();

        socket.on('message', function (data){
            console.log(data.greeting);
        }.bind(this));
    }
}
```

My back end is a simple controler

```
emit: function (req, res) {
    console.log('sending message');
    sails.sockets.broadcast('message', { greeting: 'Hola!' });
    return res.json(200, {success: true});
}
```

When I call the `emit` action I get `sending message`, but nothing logs in the front end. There are no errors anywhere, but nothing happens. If I log the socket variable I get this [image: socket log]

Is it possible to emit data from my back end Sails app to my front end Angular2 component?

Comment: Yes it is possible and Sails is bundled with a socket client: http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/web-sockets which works well and is well documented so i'm wondering why you are using a third party one?

Comment: @CraigvanTonder because I could not manage to import it in my Angular2 app with TypeScript. I tried but it constantly gave me errors. The first thing that I've checked was the sails documentation pasted. Can someone help with the current set up that I've? I'm using a `systemjs.config.js` file to include dependencies.

Comment: i found you have already implemented Socket.io, can you look at my problem in following link and let me know how can i solve it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56963376/angular-8-using-sails-js-websokcet-sokcet-io

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that you joined a room, the broadcast method only broadcasts to all the people connected in the room

```
socket.join('roomName');
```

Comment: i found you have already implemented Socket.io, can you look at my problem in following link and let me know how can i solve it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56963376/angular-8-using-sails-js-websokcet-sokcet-io